# How to register delegating handlers in a MVC Application? (not Web API)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I register a global message handler in a MVC application?

I tried registering it in my Global.asax.cs, but this handler **never** gets called whenever I access any of my endpoints in all my controllers that inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller.

However, it **does** get called when I access routes all my controllers that inherit from System.Web.Http.ApiController.

This is what I put in my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //other initializing stuff here
    **GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());** 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `Filters`. You could build something like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // do your work here
    }
}
```

and then add it to the global filters list in `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizationFilter());
```

Comment: thanks Michael. I'd love to get delegating handlers working for mvc controllers though, as they work for api controllers, and I don't want to have 2 separate pieces in filters and delegating handlers.

Comment: @HenleyChiu I would like to find out about this as well. I have a couple `DelegatingHandler` implementations in a Web API project and would like to reuse those for MVC. Since both will be in the same solution, it wouldn't be good to duplicate logic across `DelegatingHandler` and action filter implementations.